# How to unit test an In-Out component in Camel?

Tags: junit, apache-camel

I have a route setup that sends an xml document to a third party's web service that works fine, however it was Fire-and-Forget and now I need to change it to store the xml response and the http code.

An example response would be:  `<Success>TRUE</Success>`

Below is an example of my route

```
from("activemq:test_queue")
  .routeId("testRoute")
  .bean( generateTestXMLBean )
  .to( ExchangePattern.InOut, "http://www.example-webservice.com/xml" )
  .process( storeResponseProcessor )
```

Is it possible to write a unit test that mocks a HttpResponse to be returned after the route sends it to a MockEndpoint so the response can be processed?

Also am I correct in thinking that the response would become the Out message on the exchange?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can mock the HttpResponse. Normally I like to use another route to "simulate" the response. For example:

```
from("activemq:test_queue")
  .routeId("testRoute")
  .bean( generateTestXMLBean )
  .to( ExchangePattern.InOut, "direct:response" )
  .process( storeResponseProcessor )

from("direct:response")
  .routeId("testResponse")
  .setBody(simple("<Success>TRUE</Success>"))
```

Also, you can add a Mock Endpoint.

```
from("direct:response")
  .routeId("testResponse")
  .to("mock:response")
  .setBody(simple("<Success>TRUE</Success>"))
```

And yes, you're right, setting the request with InOut exchange pattern Camel will set the content in the Out Message.

Comment: Ah that's a much better way of going about it. Really helps illustrate what's happening by using another route. Thank you :)